# Django models | get specific columns

Tags: django

Is there a way to filter and get only specific columns?

For example, get all entries with the column `first_name`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[`QuerySet.values()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [`QuerySet.values_list()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), e.g.:

```
Entry.objects.values('first_name')
```

Comment: When I tried this I can no longer access the methods for the objects. How can I access the methods and still get the specific values?

Comment: You can not because it's returning an array of dictionaries, not model instances. Use `only` instead of `values`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only

Comment: Is there a way to refer to the fields not using strings? I've been looking around at documentation and I only see examples of `only()` with strings rather than referred to the fields by something like `ModelObject.<column_name>` type paradigm. As, if the column name changes I don't want to have to change the string fed into the `only()` method

Comment: how to do it like Entry.objects.values('first_name','id', 'age')

Comment: @alial-karaawi it could be Entry.objects.values(['first_name','id', 'age'])

Answer (score 24):

If you want a list of only the values, use:

```
Entry.objects.values_list('first_name', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

To only get a column's values from the table but still return an object of that model, use [`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only):

```
record = Entry.objects.only('first_name')
```

This will defer all other columns from the model but you can still access them all normally.

```
record.first_name # already retrieved
record.last_name  # retrieved on call
```

Comment: Will record.last_name run separate query to retrieve?

Comment: @kta yes, so you likely want to avoid using `only` or only access fields you passed to it.